# Apps developing languages

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I would like to learn about apps developing, I know only HTML and CSS and a few about Jquery. Where I can start to learn languages apps developing? I have an idea for some educational apps and I'd like to develop them, but I don't know how to begin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some experience with JavaScript. I'd recommend look into React Native. There are many classes on Udemy, or CodeWithMosh is a good resource. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to start by learning development natively, so I would start with either native iOS or Android. From there you could go back to React Native if you wanted to do cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Flutter (the name of the programming language is dart). Its really easy for beginners to pick up and allows you to build professional looking apps very quickly